# Creating an Influence Map within a bounded Space

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry

I am not sure if this is a math question or a computer science question, so please direct me to a better suited community if needed.

Given a bounded space G,and a set of points P, I want to create two sets of polygons of Q, and R where Q is a set of polygons where a point in P is the center of each polygon in Q, and R is a set of polygons where Q + R = G, that is R is a set of Polygons that takes up empty space between polygons in Q.

This is meant to represent an Influence/Territory Map for a set of countries where each point represents a country's center point, each polygon in Q represents a country's territory and R represented lawless or contested areas.

I did it by hand but am not sure how to translate my process algorithmically.

1. For each point in P, create an edge from each point to each other point in P, lets call this Edge Array E
2. For each edge in E, create a new edge bounded by G, that is perpendicular to the edge in E, located at the E's edge's midpoint and call this set of new edges Y
3. Take the edges Y and the closest edges of G, and construct a new polygon q where the point in P is inside q.
4. repeat this for each point in P to create the set of polygon Q
5. find the set of polygons R which is the intersection of graph G, and polygon set Q and is the left over bits.

As far as I can tell this works by hand but it looks to me that this method is O(n^2) time wise or worse and can't really be useful if I want to automate it.  Is there a better method of doing this or is there a library that can handle this?

Thank you very much for reading this.  I have attached pictures of my process by hand if my explanation proves to be insufficient.

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]
[image: Step 4]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for, thank you very much